# Selecting multiple columns from .dat files in a bash loop and merging them horizontally

Tags: bash

I am pretty much a beginner at this and am having trouble with processing .dat files. I have lots of .dat files (a_"number"_b.dat) containing 4 columns each and i would like to pull out columns 2 and 4 from each of them through a for loop and merge them horizontally in a new file i.e. pick out columns every loop and add them to the file side by side. I tried using both awk|paste statements and cut|paste statements but didn't get it working at all. In the awk case i end up with a file containing columns 2 and 4 only from the last file which was read in the loop and the cut|paste gives me a blank file. Here is the code i used:

```
for k in {1..9}
do
awk '{print $2,$4}' a_0"$k"_b.dat > atest.dat
paste atest.dat atestf.dat > atestf.dat
#cut -f2 a_0"$k"_b.dat | paste atest.dat
#cut -f4 a_0"$k"_b.dat | paste atest.dat
done
```

Example of input and output:

```
file 1:
1 10 100 1000
2 20 200 2000
3 30 300 3000
4 40 400 4000
file2:
5 50 500 5000
6 60 600 6000
7 70 700 7000
8 80 800 8000

output expected:
10 1000 50 5000
20 2000 60 6000
30 3000 70 7000
40 4000 80 8000
```

EDIT: i forgot to mention that some files have missing rows at the bottom and i would have to leave them as blank spaces when placing columns side by side.

Comment: Can't you use python for that?

Comment: Can you show an example of input and expected output?

Comment: @UbdusSamad I actually dont have much experience working with python.

Comment: @ShammelLee edited to add an example

Comment: do all files have the same number of lines?

Answer (score 0):

This one seems to work fine:

```
for ((k=1;k<=2;k++));do
tmp="$(cat mergefile)"
paste -d ' ' <(echo "$tmp") <(cut -d ' ' -f2,4 "file$k")  > mergefile
done
cat mergefile
#Output
 10 1000 50 5000                                                                                                                                                                
 20 2000 60 6000                                                                                                                                                                
 30 3000 70 7000                                                                                                                                                                
 40 4000 80 8000
```

Cut default delimiter is tab, you need to explicitly specify space as delimiter.

Same applies to paste.

You can cannot open a file for reading and on the same time for writing.
Thus , your initial attempt `paste atest.dat atestf.dat > atestf.dat` fails since file `atestf.dat` is opened for reading by past and even for writing using > (output redirection). This is the reason i'm using a tmp variable to load the data already present in `mergefile` in my solution.

Comment: I am not sure if i am not doing it correctly but using printf seems to result in merging all the data from columns close to each without any delimiters. Also some files have missing rows at the bottom so using printf is changing the group of the data as well.

Comment: @AnuragGandhi Solution changed and updated. Have a look.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

#### Input

```
  a_1_b.dat        a_2_b.dat
      |                |
      V                V

1 10 100 1000    5 50 500 5000
2 20 200 2000    6 60 600 6000
3 30 300 3000    7 70 700 7000
4 40 400 4000    8 80 800 8000
```

#### Script

```
# script.sh
dat_files=( $(find -E . -type f -maxdepth 1 -regex '^.*\/a_[0-9]+_b\.dat$') )

for line_number in $(seq 1 $(wc -l < ${dat_files[0]}))
do
  for file in ${dat_files[@]}
  do
    awk -v l=$line_number 'BEGIN {ORS=" "} NR==l {print $2, $4}' "$file"
  done
  echo
done
```

#### Script explanation

The `dat_files=...` line stores all matching files into an array. All the files in the array match following conditions…

- Regular file (`-type f`)
- File name matches the regex pattern `^.*\/a_[0-9]+_b\.dat$`

  - (`^.*\/a_`) - Starts with `a_`
  - (`[0-9]+`) - Followed by one or more digits
  - (`_b`) - Followed by `_b`
  - (`\.dat`) - Ends with `.dat`

The outer `for` loop iterates from `1` to the number of lines (`wc -l`) in the first matching file (`${dat_files[0]}`). This assumes all files have the same number of lines. So if the files have 20 lines, the outer loop iterates from `1` to `20`.

The inner `for` loop iterates all matching files and outputs fields/columns 2 and 4, adding a space at the end of each line instead of a newline character (`OFS=' '`) for each iteration. This is so that fields 2 and 4 of the next file (next iteration) are to the right of the previous fields instead of below them.

That's all there is to it!

#### Command

```
./script.sh > result.txt
```

#### Output

```
10 1000 50 5000 
20 2000 60 6000 
30 3000 70 7000 
40 4000 80 8000
```